# How do I close remote ports?

Tags: ports

I was wondering how web sites detect open ports on my network, like the [Server Port Test on whatsmyip.org](http://www.whatsmyip.org/port-scanner/server/), and how I can close these open ports (e.g. port 22 and 23)?

I'm getting these results:

[image]

Comment: What do you want ? do you want to close the port or close the response ? paste the sample output of wireshark traffic of that website.

Comment: I want to close the response, my intention is opened ports should appear as closed or timed out

Answer (score 2):

You should close the ports on the machine that has your public IP address.  This can be a computer (if it's directly connected to the Internet), or a gatewate/router/access point.

If it's a computer:

- If you're running Linux, try [disabling](http://www.aboutlinux.info/2006/04/enabling-and-disabling-services-during_01.html) some of the services.  Alternatively, you can run [iptables](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/06/iptables-rules-examples/) to drop packets to open services.  IPTables is a software firewall and will allow you to close access to TCP and UDP ports, even when their services are still running.
- Mac has a [built-in firewall](http://www.macworld.com/article/1132558/connect2504.html) that will prevent connections form being made to your machine.
- Windows has a [built in firewall](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/features/windows-firewall) as well, and so does [win8](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/windows-firewall-from-start-to-finish).

If it's a router or an access point, depending in the brand and model, there may be different ways to disable these ports.  They may be either running on the device itself, or just forwarding connections (NAT) to an internal machine.  So check both.

Looking at your screenshot, 22 and 23 are usually open these days on network devices such as routers/gateways.  If you are in control of it, consult it's manual and check in the admin panel that you can disable "remote administration" (this is usually done over ssh and/or telnet).  If you're not in charge of it, tell your network administrator to fix it.

Comment: I'm using windows 8.1, so I should create an inbound rule or a rule of Output in firewall to close that door ? thanks

Comment: You need to add inbound rules; inbound is from other machines (also that website) to your machine.  Outbound are your apps/services accessing other machines.

Answer (score 0):

I think the websites use Ping utility to detect open ports. By sending ICMP echo request packets to the desired IP address and wait for the ICMP response. Analyzing those responses (includes measuring round trips and packet loss percentage), the websites try to determine the open/closed/filtered ports.

Comment: you can tell me if it is possible to avoid or bypass this detection ? thanks guy.

Comment: What do mean by "avoid/bypass detection" ? you mean that the websites shouldn't be able to detect your network's open/closed ports?

Comment: Yes exactly I do not want sites detect which ports are open.

Comment: The sites may be using port scaning tools like nmap.You can use Port Knocking as a way to prevent this:

Comment: Sounds good can you be more specific how can I do this ?

Comment: ICMP echo requests do just that, wait for a response.  They won't tell you anything about ports, that's TCP and UDP.

Comment: @OsamaBinLaden,working on it.Will let you know when I finish

Answer (score 0):

Closing (or opening) inbound ports on your server needs to be done in the configuration of its firewall.

Whether a port appears to a scanner as *Closed* or *Timed out*, depends on the firewall's configuration: The server can be configured to either respond with a *port is closed* message, or send no reply at all.

You should also be aware of processes running on the server that listen to certain ports. If they aren't required, consider disabling them.

Comment: IPSec is usually used for VPN's, it provides a "secure tunnel".  Your firewall configuration and/or checking what services are enabled upon startup are your best bet.

Comment: Thanks @m1ke, I've edited my answer to reflect your comment.